# Did Quentin Tarantino act in all of his movies?

Tags: acting, quentin-tarantino

So, are there any Quentin Tarantino movies in which he did not act?

Comment: Have you considered comparing his director credits to his actor credits yourself? IMDb should make that pretty easy.

Comment: I prefer discussing things with people. And if somebody already knows the answer, no need for comparison..

Comment: We are not a discussion site. We also strongly encourage people to do some basic research before they ask questions here. Please see the hover text over the up and down vote arrows on any question for indication of that.

Comment: I did not realize I was breaking any kind of rules, as you can see I am new here... Should I delete my question?

Comment: Sorry, it may have come across a bit more strongly than I meant. Your question isn't against the rules - it's not against the rules to ask questions, we just recommend that you do a little research of your own first. Doing research shows that you're invested in the question, which makes us more interested in answering it. It doesn't have to be exhaustive research. Also, note that downvotes don't mean that something's against the rules, either... if it were against the rules, there would be close votes, and there are none because... this isn't against the rules.

Comment: Stack Exchange is an interesting place and we do things a bit differently than a forum because, well, we're not a forum. :D

Comment: You're also more than welcome to answer your own question, so if you decide that you're not getting the answers you want, you can do the work and report back on what you've found.

Comment: Ok, Catija, thank you for your time. I'll be more careful in the future, and for this one I'll try to answer it rather than delete it, since I see that somebody marked it as favorite question. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Marking things as favourite doesn't really mean anything. It's basically a bookmark, nothing else. If you want to know, I marked it as favourite just to keep it under surveillance, since I wasn't really sure what to make of it.

Comment: Seems like a good question. Got my upvote!

Comment: To be honest, some people here are a little snobby on what they deem as "legitimate" questions and take things rather seriously. On the other hand it makes stack exchange a delicious resource of info. Don't be discouraged. I remember my very first question on the sci-fi exchange was "Who is Darth Vader 2.0 in *The Force Awakens*?", (Kylo Ren) which in hindsight was a terrible question because I didn't attempt to google the question first. I took me a year to get that question deleted by the moderators as I was continually getting downvotes over a yr later after learning my lesson.

Answer (score 3):

Quentin Tarantino appears in several movies he has written or directed **but not in all**.

Just some examples:

He's *Mr. Brown* in *Reservoir Dogs* and *Jimmie* in *Pulp Fiction*. On the other side he only narrates the story like in *The Hateful Eight* or doesn't appear at all like in *Kill Bill Vol.1*

As mentioned before, you can look up at [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000233/) in which movies Tarantino appeared as an actor and which movies has been written by himself.

Comment: I read somewhere that Tarantino acted in Kill Bill vol. 1 as one of the Crazy 88 (the Ninja-Yakuza-Gang guys :)). However his is not credited, similar to this he also acted in the Inglorious Bastards movie where he played a dead soldier being scalped in the bat-interrogation scene. In the movies The Hateful Eight and Jackie Brown we can only hear his voice (the narrator in the first and on an answering machine in the later). So IMO he is in all of his movies - in 2 case just his voice, but still.